# Regular expression for constants in C

Tags: c, regex

I want to write regular expression for constants in C language. So I tried this:

Let

- digit -> 0-9,
- digit_oct -> 0-7,
- digit_hex -> 0-9 | a-f | A-F

Then:

- RE = digit+ U 0digit_oct+ U 0xdigit_hex+

I want to know whether I have written correct R.E. Is there any other way of writing this?

Comment: Do you only want to match _integer_ constants?

Comment: Don't forget that `098` is not a valid integer constant.

Comment: and `0b101` (on some compilers)

Comment: It appears that everybody - as usually - forgets about the `-`, sign of the number.

Comment: @Dummy00001:  Actually, no.  The `+` and `-` signs are actually the unary plus and minus operators and are not part of the integer constant.

Comment: @James: Standard-wise, language as a whole - when one has expression evaluator at hand - yes. Practically, if one writes program to say extract numeral constants from C source code (what I did many times in past) then it better not to forget about the `-`/`+` sign.

Comment: @Dummy00001: ...but the `-` in `-10` is really no different to the `/` in `15/3`.  You really *do* need an expression evaluator to do it properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is another type of integer constants, namely *integer character constants* such as `'a'` or `'\n'`. In C99 these are constants and their type is just `int`.

The best regular expressions for all these are found in the standard, section 6.4, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The 'RE' makes sense if we interpret the 'U' as being similar to set union.  However, it is more conventional to use a '|' symbol to denote alternatives.

First, you are only dealing with integer constants, not with floating point or character or string constants, let alone more complex constants.

Second, you have omitted '`0X`' as a valid hex prefix.

Third, you have omitted the various suffixes: `U`, `L`, `LL`, `ULL` (and their lower-case and mixed case synonyms and permutations).

Also, the C standard (§6.4.4.1) distinguishes between digits and non-zero digits in a decimal constant:

```
decimal-constant:
    nonzero-digit
    decimal-constant digit
```

Any integer constant starting with a zero is an octal constant, never a decimal constant.  In particular, writing `0` is writing an octal constant.

Answer (score 2):

First, C does not support Unicode literals, so you can eliminate the last rule. You also only define integer literals, not floating-point literals and not string or character literals. For the sake of my convenience I assume that that is what you intended.

```
INT    := OCTINT | DECINT | HEXINT
DECINT := [1-9] [0-9]* [uU]? [lL]? [lL]?
OCTINT := 0 [0-7]* [uU]? [lL]? [lL]?
HEXINT := 0x [0-9a-fA-F]+ [uU]? [lL]? [lL]?
```

These only describe the form of the literals, not any logic such as maximum values.

Comment: Technically, the `+` and `-` are the unary plus and minus operators and are not part of the integer constant itself.  I also _think_ that the literal `0` is considered as an octal constant (not that it matters...).

Comment: don't forget aggregate literals such as `{ 0 }`.

Comment: @Philip is this part of the formal definition of integer literals? I'm not sure ...

Comment: @Philip:  That wouldn't be an _integer constant_ (or any type of _constant,_ for that matter).

Comment: @James @wilhelm: I wasn't suggesting aggregate literals *are* integer constants, just adding to the list "not floating-point literals and not string or character literals". I could have made myself clearer.

Comment: @wilhelmtell - should that be `HEXINT := 0[xX]...` ? Also, OCTINT should not include the digits 8 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

From perl point of view I came up with the following regexp, after reading ISO C 2011:

```
my $I_CONSTANT = qr/^(?:(0[xX][a-fA-F0-9]+(?:[uU](?:ll|LL|[lL])?|(?:ll|LL|[lL])[uU]?)?)             # Hexadecimal
                      |([1-9][0-9]*(?:[uU](?:ll|LL|[lL])?|(?:ll|LL|[lL])[uU]?)?)                    # Decimal
                      |(0[0-7]*(?:[uU](?:ll|LL|[lL])?|(?:ll|LL|[lL])[uU]?)?)                        # Octal
                      |([uUL]?'(?:[^'\\\n]|\\(?:[\'\"\?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1..3}|x[a-fA-F0-9]+))+')    # Character
                    )$/x;
```